# matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplots() and add_axes() return None instead of axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

`matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplots()` ([doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=add_subplot#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot)) should return an axes.

However, doing

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
print(ax)
```

returns `None`.

Same happens for `ax = fig.add_axes()`

Why this happens and how can I obtain the axes handle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referring to the documentation of matplotlib 3.1. In matplotlib 3.1

```
ax = fig.add_subplot()
```

adds a subplot and returns it.

However you are running your code in a prior version. In matplotlib < 3.1 you will need to explicitly state the position of the subplot in the grid

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

---

`fig.add_axes()` is a lower level function, it will add an axes (not a subplot on a grid), so it **needs** an argument, namely the position of the axes in figure coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what kind of subplot you are adding as following. Here, 111 means 1 row, 1 column. The last index specifies the index of the current subplot.

If you have 1 row and 2 columns, then you will need to add twice: `121` and `122`. Now, `121` would mean 1 row, 2 column and **1st subplot**. Similarly, `122` would mean 1 row, 2 column and **2nd subplot**

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
print (ax)
# AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
```

Comment: Why this happens also with `add_axes()`? Moreover the doc says that the default is 111, so why is the handle not returned if I use the default value? Is this an error in the doc?

Comment: @LucaAmerio : ImportanceOfBeingEarnest's answered it. I am also using matplotlib 2.2.2 so I saw the same effect as you. Indeed [docs](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) for matplotlib 2 says nothing about default